# How to display data from MYSQL database as bootstrap progress bar using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've been trying to use PHP to display points from matching user ID using in the bootstrap progress bar. The starting value for each user is 10 out of 100 but my progress bar is not showing anything. and I'm getting an error saying "Warning: Undefined array key "Points" in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\index.php on line 9"
**Heres what I got in my index.php**
[my %percent declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVrkk.png)

[my bootstrap progress bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2b6hs.png)

**My connection.php**
[connection.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaAVu.png)

**session.php**
[session.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvATu.png)

**error and output**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4oAW.png)

Comment: You could have taken the screenshot of the question as well and add it as an image. 

Please don't put code as image, no one really bothers about writing the code from image and then reproducing the issue that you are facing. Put the code as text.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.